# Is it ok that a roofing nail is in a gap between sheathing boards?

Tags: roof, nails

There is a dangling nail in the new shingle roof I had installed. Will it be okay?

[image]

Comment: Would not worry about it too much.  One nail won't cause the roof to fail.  Would probably cause more damage trying to remove it.

Comment: Without knowing what specific roofing product they put on your roof, I'd be more concerned (assuming that's a standard wood roof decking) that there are barely any other nails visible, indicating that the nails likely weren't long enough to fully penetrate the decking and not providing as much holding power as they should.

Comment: @Milwrdfan I see two nails, right along that crack in the bottom layer of the ply, just sticking through. However, you're right, those aren't 1-1/4 nails unless there's something on the topside we're not seeing (or that's 1" decking)

Comment: Just watch your head. I was doing insulation in an attic a couple of decades ago in close to the soffit, and a head-lift required 60 stitches to close.

Answer (score 7):

This is a common occurrence  with shingle roofs. Hopefully the nails holding down the shingles go into the wood but there will be some that knock out knots or just go between two pieces of decking. The nails go through the top part of the strip of shingles and then are covered up by the next row of overlapping shingles. There wouldn't be any problems unless that top row got damaged and water was able to leak under the nail head.

Answer (score 0):

I can see ~10 nails penetrating the sheathing.  It is hard to tell but it looks like only the nail tips are penetrating.

"When 1″ nails are used to fasten asphalt shingles to 1/2″ roof sheathing, only the very tip of the nail will penetrate the roof sheathing.  Over time, expansion and contraction of the roof sheathing can force the nail back up and out of the roof.  When this happens, the shingle tabs get lifted up.  On three-tab shingles, these lifted areas are often visible from the ground."

There are some good pictures that show proper nail penetration on the site below - your nails are too short in comparison.

https://structuretech.com/short-shingle-nails